# A debug webpage made on vscode doesn't show the expected visualization

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

how are you?. I'm making several exercises from a book but because the code in the book appears to be run in pastebin or some related then I'm doing it with vscode and debbuging it on google chrome. The code of index.html is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Today's Date</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="variables-3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</body>

</html>
```

the code in style.css is the following

```
body {
    background-color: #0080ff;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    color: #f0f;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and the javascript code in varable-3.js is the following

```
var div,
    container = document.getElementById('container');
for(var i = 0; i<5;i++)
{
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.onclick = function()
    {
        alert('This is box #'+i);
    }
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

my launch.json is

```
{
    "name": "Launch localhost",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500/",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/wwroot",
    "runtimeExecutable":"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
},
```

and my settings.json is

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.port": 5500,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser" : "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "chrome --incognito --remote-debugging- 
     port=9222",
    "liveServer.settings.NoBrowser" : false,
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles" : [
        ".vscode/**",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.sass"
    ]

}
```

this suppose to show the background in some kind of sea blue and in the boddy around five squares in other color but only shows all the page in sea blue and I don't know why that is happening.

NOTE: here are code from several sources and including from other posts, I'm also using vscode-live-server.

How can I solve that problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your IDE and server are irrelevant. This code and markup is not going to work for a variety of reasons: there is no "container" element under which to append your 5 children div elements, you won't see the children div elements because they have no content, and you can't assign event listeners to dynamically created elements this way.

Comment: Thanks for your commen, I looked into the books repository and I made some distribution of what they did. The working files are as follows in the next answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I wanna point that the following is only a modification of what the author did more a rearange than other thing, now the files:

index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Let</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

 <body>
    <h1>Click on a box</h1>
        <div id="container"></div>
    <h1>
    <script src="variables-3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

variable-3.js is the same.

style.css is

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#container>div {
    height:  5em;
    width: 5em;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

And now it works.